# How to read the file from excel and write in a text file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am able to convert excel file into text file, but need help with formatting the result.

Example: I have excel file

Cell A = "H"    Cell B = "XYZ"

Result in TEXT file I need :

H  (20 SPACES IN BETWEEN) XYZ

Comment: Please format the question properly

Comment: Use pandas to read the excel file then write the text file manually.  An f-string might help with that. Show us your attempt to solve the problem and others will help.

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
import pandas as pd 

# Read in your data
df = pd.read_excel("your_file.xlsx")

# Write to txt file
with open("test.txt", "w") as f_out:
    for (i, row) in df.iterrows():
        out = ""
        for j, el in enumerate(row):
            if j == 0:
                out += el
            elif "@" in el:
                out += " "*48 + el
                
            else: 
                out += " - " + el
        
        out += " - " + " "*(1221-len(out)-3)   
        f_out.write(out)
```